# Stored Procedure Gets Correct Rows But SqlDataAdapter Does Not Fill Same Amount of Rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net, sqldataadapter

I have a VS2010 .Net 4.0 Web Service that is supposed to return a DataTable of records.  It seems to have been working great until today.  If I pass in the 5 parameters (3 int's and 2 datetimes) to it via SQL Server Management Studio I get all of the rows back I expect.  However, when I run in through the service and inspect the variable on the ds.Fill(MyTable) line, some of the rows to not show.

Something odd that I just noticed, when I search on items with TagNumber 1-270 I get all of the rows in the SSMS and in the .Fill.  Any time I try to return items with TagNumbers between 271 and 300, all of those rows show in SSMS but none of them come back in the .Fill.  Everything I have checked over 300 works in both as expected.

Here is my stored procecdure.  Not special that I can tell.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[FetchLicenseReceiptData] (
    @ForYear INT,
    @StartNumber INT,
    @EndNumber INT,
    @StartDate DATETIME,
    @EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
-- Also update udf GetLicenseReceiptData

SELECT
    DISTINCT
    -- License Fields
    l.BarCode,
    l.TagNumber,
    l.Issued,
    l.ForYear,
    l.Fee,
    l.WebOrderNumber,
    lts.Name AS TagStyle,
    CAST(CAST((l.ForYear + 1) AS VARCHAR) + '-01-31' AS DATETIME) AS RenewalDate,
    -- Dog Fields
    d.Name AS DogName,
    d.BirthDate,
    d.SpayNeuter,
    d.Deceased,
    lb.Name AS Breed,
    lhl.Name AS HairLength,
    lpc.Name AS PrimaryColor,
    lsc.Name AS SecondaryColor,
    lx.Name AS Sex,
    -- Owner Fields
    lt.Name AS Title,
    o.FirstName,
    o.Initial,
    o.LastName,
    -- Address Fields
    a.Address1,
    a.Address2,
    a.City,
    a.County,
    ls.Abbreviation AS State,
    a.ZipCode,
    -- Contact Fields
    jpi.PhoneNumber AS PrimaryPhoneNumber,
    jpi.PhoneType AS PrimaryPhoneType,
    jei.EmailAddress AS PrimaryEmail,
    jei.EmailType AS PrimaryEmailType
FROM
                    data.License      AS   l
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data.Dog          AS   d ON l.DogID = d.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data.Owner        AS   o ON d.OwnerID = o.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN data.Address      AS   a ON o.AddressID = a.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.Title      AS  lt ON o.TitleID = lt.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.State      AS  ls ON a.StateID = ls.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.TagStyle   AS lts ON l.TagStyleID = lts.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.Breed      AS  lb ON d.BreedID = lb.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.HairLength AS lhl ON d.HairLengthID = lhl.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.Color      AS lpc ON d.PrimaryColorID = lpc.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.Color      AS lsc ON d.SecondaryColorID = lsc.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.Sex        AS  lx ON d.SexID = lx.ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            p.Number AS PhoneNumber,
            lpt.Name AS PhoneType,
            op.OwnerID AS OwnerID
        FROM
                            data.OwnerPhone  AS  op
            LEFT OUTER JOIN data.Phone       AS   p ON op.PhoneID = p.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.PhoneType AS lpt ON p.PhoneTypeID = lpt.ID
        WHERE
            p.IsPrimary = 1
    ) AS jpi ON o.ID = jpi.OwnerID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            e.Address AS EmailAddress,
            let.Name AS EmailType,
            oe.OwnerID AS OwnerID
        FROM
                            data.OwnerEmail  AS  oe
            LEFT OUTER JOIN data.Email       AS   e ON oe.EmailID = e.ID
            LEFT OUTER JOIN lookup.EmailType AS let ON e.EmailTypeID = let.ID
        WHERE
            e.IsPrimary = 1
    ) AS jei ON o.ID = jei.OwnerID
WHERE
        l.ForYear = @ForYear
    AND l.TagNumber >= @StartNumber
    AND l.TagNumber <= @EndNumber
    AND l.Issued >= @StartDate
    AND l.Issued <= @EndDate
ORDER BY
    l.TagNumber
```

END

End here is my method that gets called to call the SP:

```
    public DataTable FetchLicenseReceiptData(int ForYear, int StartNumber, int EndNumber, DateTime StartDate, DateTime EndDate) {
        DataTable Result = new DataTable();

        try {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DogLicensingContext"].ConnectionString)) {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("FetchLicenseReceiptData", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ForYear", ForYear));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartNumber", StartNumber));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndNumber", EndNumber));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@StartDate", StartDate));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@EndDate", EndDate));

                con.Open();

                SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ds.Fill(Result);
                Result.TableName = "LicenseReceiptDataAutoPrint";
            } // using the connection
        } catch (Exception e) {

        } // try-catch

        return Result;
    } // FetchLicenseReceiptData - Method
```

So in SSMS when I run the following:

FetchLicenseReceiptData 2013, 270, 271, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'

I get 2 records.  When run via the .Fill I only get one (the 270)

And when I run the following in SSMS:

FetchLicenseReceiptData 2013, 271, 300, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'

I get all 30 rows.  But via the .Fill it returns none.

Lastly, if I run the following:

FetchLicenseReceiptData 2013, 301, 310, '2012-01-01', '2012-12-31'

I get all 10 in both SSMS and .Fill.

As an example of the data that comes back, here is the 270 and 271 data that comes back in SSMS.  I replaced the tab with the tilde (~) character

01CA2013T000270~270~2012-12-12 16:10:58.273~2013~20.00~NULL~Standard~2014-01-31 00:00:00.000~Theo~2008-02-13 00:00:00.000~0~0~Shar Pei~Short~Apricot~White~Male~Unknown~cccccccc~~kkkkkkk~4444 RICHLAND AVE.~~xxxxxx~~OH~44444~5555555~Home~NULL~NULL

01CA2013T000271~271~2012-12-13 08:44:58.670~2013~20.00~NULL~Standard~2014-01-31 00:00:00.000~SAMSON~1999-12-12 00:00:00.000~1~0~Labrador Retriever~Medium~Black~Unknown~Male~Ms~xxxxx~~xxxxxxxxxx~4444 GIEL AVE~~xxxxxx~~OH~44444~5555555~Home~xxxxxx~Personal

This one is quite odd.  Hope one of you guru's can assist me.

**SOLUTION:**
Thanks to @EJBrennan for the SQL Profiler suggestion.  I had never used it before but it pointed me in the correct direction.  Here is was was actually being sent to SQL:

exec FetchLicenseReceiptData @ForYear=2013,@StartNumber=270,@EndNumber=271,@StartDate='2012-01-01 00:00:00',@EndDate='2012-12-13 00:00:00'

When I ran that, it gave me 1 row instead of 2.  Essentially the values are the same EXCEPT for the 00:00:00 for the time.  I wound up adding the following to the top of my stored procedure to force things to be correct:

```
SET @StartDate = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate), 0) -- Beginning of given Date
SET @EndDate   = DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @EndDate),   1) -- End of given Date
```

This takes whatever @StartDate was passed in and forces it to 0:0:0 of that day.  Then it sets @EndDate to the NEXT day and also 0:0:0 for the time.

Also at the bottom of the SP in the WHERE clause, I changed the <= @EndDate to be < EndDate since now, @EndDate is one day AFTER the date passed in.

Thanks again @EJBrennan

Comment: You should use SQL profiler to trace and copy/paste exactly the sql that is being sent from your app to sql server. And after you capture it, paste it into SSMS and see if the results are the same or different than what you are manually keying into SSMS - you need to rule out 'user' error. You also want to make sure that the database and server you are running against with your app, is the same one you are running against with SSMS, and not a test or dev version of the database for example.

Comment: Try doing the fill into a dataset instead of a datatable and see what you get inside the dataset. In particular, check the dataset to see if there are multiple tables created.